# Validating ItemsControl on Button click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl with an item template that contains two ComboBoxes. For any given item, the second ComboBox is required iff the first ComboBox has a selected value. I have set this validation up using IDataErrorInfo on the view model.

Rather than flagging ComboBox #2 as invalid the second a user selects a value in ComboBox1, I want to perform the validation when the user tries to save. It's kind of annoying to have a form "yell" at you for doing something wrong on a field you haven't even had a chance to enter yet.

Normally you could force this validation by retrieving the BindingExpression for the ComboBox and calling UpdateSource() and then determine if there is an error by calling Validation.GetHasError() passing the ComboBox. Since the ComboBoxes are generated dynamically by the ItemsControl, it is not as easy to get to. So I have 2 questions: 1. How do you ensure validation has executed for all controls when the save button is clicked. 2. How do you check whether there are validation errors when the save button is clicked. Validation.GetHasError remains false for the ItemsControl even when a ComboBox2 within it has an error. Thanks.

EDIT:
I had followed [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx) to implement IDataErrorInfo in order to validate the combobox properties relative to each other.

```
public class IntroViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public Guid ClassScheduleID
    {
        get { return _intro.ClassScheduleID; }
        set
        {
            _intro.ClassScheduleID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ClassScheduleID");

            //OnPropertyChanged("TrialDate"); //This will trigger validation on ComboBox2 when bound ComboBox1 changes
        }
    }

    public DateTime TrialDate
    {
        get { return _intro.TrialDate; }
        set
        {
            _intro.TrialDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TrialDate");
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get { return ValidateProperty(columnName); }
    }

    private string ValidateProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        string error = null;

        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "TrialDate":
                if (_intro.TrialDate == DateTime.MinValue && _intro.ClassScheduleID != Guid.Empty)
                    error = "Required";
                break;
            default:
                error = null;
                break;
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post a sample for your view model?

Comment: *It's kind of annoying to have a form "yell" at you for doing something wrong on a field you haven't even had a chance to enter yet*... perhaps, but it's not so annoying to have a list of changes that need to be made to make a data entry form valid presented to you in a friendly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I accomplished it while waiting for answers. When a save is intiated, ValidateTrials() is called to ensure validation has fired for the comboboxes and then TrialsHaveErrors() is called to check whether there are validation errors on them. This is the brute force approach I'd like to avoid, but it does work.

```
    //Force validation on each combobox2
    private void ValidateTrials()
    {
        foreach (IntroViewModel introVm in icTrials.Items)
        {
            ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)icTrials.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(introVm);

            if (cp == null) continue;

            ComboBox cb2 = (ComboBox)cp.ContentTemplate.FindName("cb2", (FrameworkElement)cp);

            //Update the source to force validation.
            cb2.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty).UpdateSource();
        }
    }

    //Recursively searches the Visual Tree for ComboBox elements and checks their errors state
    public bool TrialsHaveError(DependencyObject ipElement)
    {
        if (ipElement!= null)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ipElement); x++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ipElement, x);
                if (child != null && child is ComboBox)
                {
                    if (Validation.GetHasError(child))
                        return true;
                }

                if (TrialsHaveError(child)) return true;   //We found a combobox with an error
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Slimmed down XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl Name="icTrials" ItemsSource="{Binding Intros}" Margin="10,6,10,0" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="2">

                        <ComboBox Name="cb1"
                                    SelectedValuePath="ID"
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ClassScheduleID, Converter={StaticResource nullEmptyConverter}, ConverterParameter=System.Guid}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ClassesSource}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    ...
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>

                        <ComboBox Name="cb2" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableStartDates}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Date"
                                    ItemStringFormat="{}{0:d}"
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TrialDate, Converter={StaticResource nullEmptyConverter}, ConverterParameter=System.DateTime, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                        </ComboBox>


                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

To avoid the issue of flagging the field invalid before the user has had a chance to set it, I updated the setter for cb1's bound property, ClassScheduleID to conditionally fire notification for the TrialDate property depending on how the value is changing.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to create the behavior you need based on some assumptions

sample

XAML

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Command="{Binding AddItem}"
                Content="Add Item" />
        <Button Command="{Binding Save}"
                Content="Save" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="2"
                        Margin="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="value1" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding Value1}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sampleData}}" />
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding Value2}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource sampleData}}"
                                  Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValid}"
                                 Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="border"
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Main VM

```cs
    public ViewModel()
    {

        AddItem = new SimpleCommand(i => Data.Add(new DataViewModel(new DataModel())));
        Save = new SimpleCommand(i =>
            {
                foreach (var vm in Data)
                {
                    vm.ValidateAndSave();
                }
            }
        );
        Data = new ObservableCollection<DataViewModel>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DataViewModel> Data { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddItem { get; set; }
    public ICommand Save { get; set; }
```

data VM and model

```cs
public class DataModel
{
    public object Value1 { get; set; }
    public object Value2 { get; set; }
}

public class DataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DataModel model;
    public DataViewModel(DataModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        IsValid = true;
    }

    object _value1;
    public object Value1
    {
        get
        {
            return _value1;
        }
        set
        {
            _value1 = value;
        }
    }

    object _value2;
    public object Value2
    {
        get
        {
            return _value2;
        }
        set
        {
            _value2 = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    public void ValidateAndSave()
    {
        IsValid = !(_value1 != null && _value2 == null);
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsValid"));

        if (IsValid)
        {
            model.Value1 = _value1;
            model.Value2 = _value2;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

so the VM will validate all the items when you click save and will save only those items which are valid. otherwise will mark the IsValid property to false which will be notified to UI

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together pushpraj. That is an option. I am looking to  take advantage of WPF's built in Validation mechanisms if possible, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell how you've implemented the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in your code, but in my implementation, doing what you want is simple. For future users, you can find out about this interface on the [`IDataErrorInfo` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) page on MSDN. On the linked page, you will see that you need to implement the `Item` indexer and the `Error` property.

That's all you need, because if you have implemented it correctly, then you can find out if your data (implementing) item has an error by simply checking the value of the `Error` property:

```
bool hasError = string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourDataTypeInstance.Error);
if (!hasError) Save(yourDataTypeInstance);
else MessageBox.Show("Invalid data!");
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Try using this instead:

```
public DateTime TrialDate
{
    get { return _intro.TrialDate; }
    set
    {
        _intro.TrialDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TrialDate");
        OnPropertyChanged("Error");

    }
}

public string Error
{
    get { return this["TrialDate"]; }
}
```

I'll leave you to work out the rest, which is essentially managing `string`s.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how that got cut out. I updated my code w/ the implementation. I'm only using IDataErrorInfo for properties that are dependent on one another but using ValidationRules for required fields, number ranges, etc. I had left Error unused intentionally in this case, but I have also not found how it's intended to be set.

Comment: So when using IDataErrorInfo, Error should go through and perform validation on each property each time it is called then? This lets me perform the validation properly. It leaves me still needing a solution for displaying the error since I'm not wanting it to display initially. I think part of my interim solution below can deal with that. Thanks for your help!